# Ruby on Rails: Dynamically choose a class to search from

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do i have a variable such that sometime I can do

```
Foo.find(id)
```

or sometimes

```
Bar.find(id)
```

there not constants so .constantize won't work =\

Comment: can you explain your last stmt? why do you think constantize wont work?

Comment: Because model's aren't constants? i haven't tested it.. just a hunch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
klass = Foo # This could easily be in some kind of conditional statement
klass.find(...)
```

and of course `Foo` and `Bar` in your example *are* constants, so you could easily also do

```
"Foo".constantize.find(...)
```